# How to get state in Nuxt js with composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
setup(){
const columns = computed(()=>store.state['subCategory'].subCategoryColumnsData[subCategoryName.value]);

const { fetch } = useFetch(async () => {
     
     await store.dispatch('subCategory/getColumnsQuery', { 
          categories: subCategoryId.value,
          page: 1, 
          subCategoryName: subCategoryName.value, 
        }) 
    });

fetch();
}
```

I want to switch between pages in my project. Whenever I switched another page, I send request to get data with latest updates. This code works well for the first time when page was loaded, but it doesn't work when I switched from one page to another page. But if I check store state, I can see it in store. If I visit same page second time , I can see data this time.

**But if I change my code like this, it works well. I did not get why it does not work true in the first sample**

```
setup(){
const columns = ref([]) 

const { fetch } = useFetch(async () => {
     
     await store.dispatch('subCategory/getColumnsQuery', { 
          categories: subCategoryId.value,
          page: 1, 
          subCategoryName: subCategoryName.value, 
        }) 
    }).then(() => (columns.value = store.state['subCategory'].subCategoryColumnsData[subCategoryName.value]));

fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you test it? sample:

```
const state = reactive({ columns: computed(() => yourstore })
// do not need to call fetch because this hook is a function
useFetch(async () => { await store.dispatch(url) })
return {
  ...toRefs(state),
}
```

Comment: it does not work . can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626121/how-to-get-state-in-nuxt-js-store-component.  more detailed